# String Copying in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

How can I copy strings in C so that do not overlap the old values? I'd used `strcpy()`  but it clean `dest` to set values of `src`.

```
char* foo =  "  This    is my     string    \0";
char* new = malloc(strlen(str) + 1);
char* token;
int size = 0;

token = strtok(foo, " \t");
while( NULL != token ) 
{   
    int i; 
    for(i = 0; token[i] != '\0'; i++)  
    {
        new[size++] = token[i];
    }

    new[size++] = ' ';
    token = strtok(NULL, " \t");
}
new[size] = '\0';
```

I want an alternative for this block of code:

```
int i; 
for(i = 0; token[i] != '\0'; i++)  
{
    new[size++] = token[i];
}

new[size++] = ' ';
```

There is an native method in C for do this? I not found any function in `string.h`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please work on your code formatting, and as a general rule, don't ever name a variable `new` in C, as if your code was ever to be used in a C++ project, it would cause a LOT of headaches.

Comment: Wait, what's wrong with `strcpy`?  That seems to be exactly what you should be using.

Comment: `strncpy` should be what you are looking for. Or, can you elaborate on your problem so we know what you actually want to do? Of course `dest` is being cleaned?!

Comment: Bugs: You didn't check malloc for NULL, you called a local "new", you called strtok, you have a potential integer overflow if you pass in a 4GB-1 byte string, i is signed and can wrap if foo is longer than 2GB.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: it is only example code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about [strdup](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup)? It even allocates the target buffer for you.

Comment: I think it would be better to recommend `strndup` …

Comment: If `strtok` is used, `strncpy` and `strndup` do not need to be used.  However, the code is applying `strtok` to a string literal (pointed to by `foo`), which is a no-no.  Perhaps `strspn` and `strcspn` should be used instead of `strtok`.